# Unequal number of requests sent with Gatling

Tags: performance, gatling

My intent was to have 2000 virtual users simultaneously hit an API with two different urls,  The result was that the first url finished all the requests and the second url only finished 168.  What am I doing wrong to cause the second url to only publish part of the results;

```
class hammer1 extends Simulation {

  val repeatCount = 2000
  val concurrentUsers = 100

  object Post {
      // repeat is a loop resolved at RUNTIME
      val post = repeat(repeatCount, "i") { // Note how we force the counter name so we can reuse it
          exec(http("Post")
              .post("/postData")
              .header(HttpHeaderNames.ContentType, HttpHeaderValues.ApplicationJson)
              .queryParam("""size""", "1000")
              .body(StringBody("""{"payload":"Large number of 9s"}""")
             )
            .pause(1)
       }
  }

  object Get {
      // repeat is a loop resolved at RUNTIME
      val get = repeat(repeatCount, "i") { // Note how we force the counter name so we can reuse it
          exec(http("Get")
              .get("/getData")
            )
        .     pause(1)
       }
   }
  val httpConf = http
     //.baseURL("http://<url>")
     //.baseURL("http://localhost:10010")
.     baseURL("http://<url>")

  val posters = scenario("Posters").exec(Post.post)
  val getters = scenario("Getters").exec(Get.get)

  setUp(posters.inject(rampUsers(concurrentUsers) over (10 seconds)),
    getters.inject(rampUsers(concurrentUsers) over (10 seconds))
  ).protocols(httpConf)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My2cents: content gets served to getters with an Expire date header, so it was cached.
See [caching documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.1/http/http_protocol.html?highlight=caching#caching).

Then, could you please validate answers to your previous question?